# How can i overwrite data on HTML Datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

On a template i'm receiving data from a Websocket connection, here is how i receive it:

```
<script language="javascript">
    mySocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('data', data);
        $('history').append('</td><td>'+data['Rate']+'</td><td>'+data['Quantity']+'</td></tr>')
    };
</script>
```

And on my HTML i have a datatable:

```
<table class=" table table-hover" id="history">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>RATE</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
```

Every time i receive a message, the content of the message is appended to the table. This code **works** without any issue, the problem is that it will keep adding data to the table, making the table really big and ugly to see.

What i want, instead, is this: the table keeps a fixed height of 10 records, so every time a new message is received, the message is appended at the **first** row of the table, and the message that is at the tenth place of the table disappears. Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your code is not working.

Change it as following.

```
<table class=" table table-hover" id="history">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>RATE</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript">
    mySocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('data', data);
        $('#history > tbody').prepend('<tr><td>'+data['Rate']+'</td><td>'+data['Quantity']+'</td></tr>');
        if ($('#history > tbody > tr').length > 10) {
           $('#history > tbody > tr:last-child').remove();
        }

    };
</script>
```

```js
 var ind = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        ind++;
        $('#history > tbody').prepend('<tr><td>aaa' + ind + '</td><td>bbb</td></tr>');
        if ($('#history > tbody > tr').length > 10) {
            $('#history > tbody > tr:last-child').remove();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class=" table table-hover" id="history">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>RATE</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this, but it will only add the first 10 records and after that it won't append anything, even when a new message is received

Comment: @Jack022 Perhaps new message will be added table's first row.